# IntelliJ Update Projects command not tracking remote Git branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

The IntelliJ "Update Project" command doesn't update my current Git branch to track the remote's (possibly update) branch.

I can see IntelliJ fetches the changes from the remote repo when I run <kbd>Update Project</kbd> by looking at the Git Console in IntelliJ (output below). However, the branch isn't updated to point at the new remote.

```
# From IntelliJ Git console after running Update Project
git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false \
    -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin \
    --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune
```

I can use `git pull` from the terminal and everything works as expected. Output of `git pull --verbose`:

```
# Manually run in terminal
git pull --verbose
From github.com:<correct-user>/<repo>
 = [up to date]        main                                -> origin/main
Updating 539c02cd..0b832f3d
Fast-forward
```

How do I configure IntelliJ's <kbd>Update Project</kbd> to fast-forward my branches to track the remote branch?

**Environment Info**

- git version 2.23.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021

Output of `git remote -v`:

```
origin  git@github.com:<correct-user>/<repo>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<correct-user>/<repo>.git (push)
```

Output of `git show-ref main`

```
529c02bd0b44485abd1f4318de393a9de1255372 refs/heads/main
9ee216efe65d6df00e33908f17466c810653038a refs/heads/origin/main
928859fd80c1bcbea9ad5a0905165f65b8d6634e refs/original/refs/heads/main
0b932f7d5104140feb9efdacf59d424ba00ec443 refs/remotes/origin/main
```

Update: IntelliJ Git console output after Update Project

[image: IntelliJ Git Update project]

Comment: Could you please check what do you see in Event Log once you run "Update project"? there should be fetch + rebase or fetch + merge when you run "Update Project", if there is no second command (rebase/merge) it may mean that your branch is up to date.

Comment: The event log only shows `git fetch origin` and reports "All files are up to date". There's no rebase after the fetch. I know that's not correct; origin/main is 4 commits ahead of my main. I added a screenshot of the IntelliJ git console after running Update Project.